# trying to make win32 console dll file but having some problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

Hello every i want to create a simple dll file from c++ code in visual basic 10 but getting some error here is the code
the function of this dll is to input any name and display the name when it is called by another application(both are console application)

```
//This is demo.h file
#ifdef DEMODLL_EXPORTS
#define DEMODLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DEMO_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace Demo
{
class mydemo
{
char name[30];
public:
    static DEMODLL_API char getdata(char name);
    static DEMODLL_API char displaydata(char name);
};
}
```

and this is demo.cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "demo.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std; 
namespace Demo
{
char mydemo :: getdata(char name)
char mydemo :: displaydata(char name)
{
    return name;
}
 }
```

these are the errors

```
 demo.h(13): error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ';'
 demo.h(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 demo.h(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 demo.h(14): error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ';'
 demo.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 demo.h(14): error C2086: 'int Demo::mydemo::DEMODLL_API' : redefinition
 demo.h(13) : see declaration of 'Demo::mydemo::DEMODLL_API'
 demo.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 demo.cpp(12): error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ';'
 demo.cpp(12): error C2761: 'char Demo::mydemo::getdata(char)' : member function redeclaration not allowed
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #ifdef DEMODLL_EXPORTS
> #define DEMODLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
> #else
> #define DEMO_API __declspec(dllimport)
> #endif
> ```

You are defining one macro when `DEMODLL_EXPORTS` is defined, and a different macro (with a different name) when `DEMODLL_EXPORTS` is not defined. In the build where you get these errors, the symbol `DEMODLL_API` is not defined as a macro, so the compiler believes it to be an identifier (which was never declared).

> ```
> char mydemo :: getdata(char name)
> char mydemo :: displaydata(char name) {...}
> ```

This doesn't make much sense. Did you plan to provide a body for `getdata`?